# Uploading Images from form to file system

Tags: php, html

I want to let my users upload an image thta needs to be stored in mjy website file system. How do i do that?

this is what i have till now -

```
<form action="js.php">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="file" name="image"/>
</form>
```

I want it via PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: first of all, you should set the enctype of the form to multipart/form-data